# JPA delete not cascading to FK and no errors reported

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-keys, cascade, many-to-one

I have 2 simple tables Question (parent table) and Answer (child), where Question has 1:Many Answers implemented as:

```
public class Answer {
    ....
        @JsonBackReference
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="questionId")
        private Question question;
```

and

```
public class Question{
...
   @JsonManagedReference
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="question", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<Answer> answer;
```

The mysql database has a PK / FK established, and when trying to delete in SQL fails (as expected) if I try to delete from Question (no cascades are in place in the database), as evidenced by the following test done in SQL:

```
mysql> delete from question where id = 3;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quizdb`.`answer`, CONSTRAINT `answer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`questionId`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`))
```

Here's my code trying to delete the question and answer:

```
public boolean deleteQuestion(int qid) {
    boolean status = false;

    Question question = em.find(Question.class, qid);
    System.out.println("Question to go: " + question);
    try {
        em.remove(question);
        em.flush();   // added per comment, but still broken
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    question = em.find(Question.class, qid); 
    System.out.println("question found? " + question);
    return question == null;
```

It em.finds the question, no errors or messages in console, on the 2nd find attempt, it states: "question found? null", as one would expect and the method returns True, BUT the question row still resides in the table, and no cascade to child answers.  Any clues are appreciated.

Comment: try `em.flush()`

Comment: Just tried that on your advise (thank you), but row still not removed.  Though now "return question == null" returns false (and still no errors about FK or anything). BTW, autocommit is enabled as well.

Comment: Where is your transaction? Have you checked sql provider logs?

Comment: A [mcve] please.